# Unable to launch the UWP application usinhg LaunchUriAsync

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, deep-linking, launcher

I was trying to launch the UWP application using `Launcher.LaunchUriasync(new Uri("protocol"))`. It works fine in the RS4 OS version (17134). When I was trying to run the same application in RS5 OS version (17738) the same function returns value as false, it was unable to launch the application.
In the event viewer the error message displays as

> WindowsSystem..Launcher.LaunchUriasync(Uri uri) failed because the URI scheme "myprotocolname" is not supportrd by this API

Comment: Could you post the actual URI scheme you are using?

Comment: Are you missing the colon?

Comment: Also, could you try updating to the latest Insider Preview build? Maybe the problem was only temporary in the 17738 version

Comment: @Vishnu s, I have tested with latest OS version(17751.1), and the issue does not appear, if the issue really exist in 17738, please try to update to latest version.

Comment: I have Updated the OS to 17751 the issue still exists. Actually the application is not compact-able with the device. I have not installed the application from store. I installed it  as a local package. I can see the protocol of that application in the settings app. when i was trying to launch the application from start menu it launches as popup and show message"This app is not compactable with the device". using protocol in the run command also launches the application with the same message.In the RS4OS also it works in the same way. But after upgrading the OS to RS5 I am facing this issue.

Comment: Could you share more code or simple sample that could reproduce this issue?